# Denoising in compositing better than original denoising?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

Is the denoising in the compositor better than the cycles denoising?
I’ve heard it is but just to make sure I want some opinions. I’m looking for faster render basically anyways.

Comment: Different denoisers, different drawbacks. Just test it. OIDN and OPTIX are also different.